# Create custom function to delete context in parentheses from string

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a custom function that allows me to delete content in parentheses from a string. Say I have a string: "508 (7S9 5DU) 609 (609)", I would like to have a function that takes in this string and turns in into "508 609".

I have been playing around a little bit with the VBA editor, but my VBA programming skills are very limited, not to say non-existant.

I came up with the following concise bit of code, but unfortunately it does not do the job:

```
Function DelPar(Source As Range)

Source.Replace What:="(*) ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Function
```

When I type in "=DelPar(source reference)", I obtain "0" as value...

Thanks for your help in advance,

Best regards.

Comment: placing the wildcard character within parentheses makes it search for the litteral wildcard character, not for  the part of the string within brackets.

Comment: You will probably want to use string manipulation built-ins for that. Such as [`instr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instr-function). First look for an opening parenthesis, then for the following closing one. With those positions you can then `Replace()` what you want to throw away or build a new string with `Left()` and `Right()`. Usually I'd say using Regular Expressions would be the way to go, but I can't really recommend that in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `Range.Replace` in a UDF. You could use Regex like this:

```
Function DelPar(Source As String)
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = "\([\w ]+\)"
      DelPar = Application.Trim(.Replace(Source, ""))
   End With
End Function
```

Comment: It might be better to accept a `Variant` rather than a `Range`, so that you can use it with normal strings (e.g. concatenated or from a lookup).  +1 for good & concise code though :)

Comment: @Chronocidal Fair point, though no need for a Variant. Updated the code to use a String.

Comment: Perfect one. Simple and effective. Nice job

Comment: @DriesWeytjens Please, mark the answer as correct, so this question will be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This macro will first count how many pairs of `"("` and `")"` there are <s>- although, it currently does not distinguish between `"(*)"` and `")*("`</s> **{EDIT}** *Added a check to exit the While loop early if no `"(*)"` exist, only `")*("`, and made the loop count application-agnostic by replacing the `WorksheetFunction.Max`*

It then loops through once for each pair, and builds a string that starts with a `"("`, and runs until the next `")"`, and replaces that string with `""` (i.e. deletes it).  **If it hits a second `"("` before it reaches `")"`, then it restarts the string from `"("`.**

```
Function ExciseBracketedText(ByVal Text As String, Optional TrimSpaces AS Boolean = False) As String
    Dim lBracketCount As Long, sExcise As String, lCounter As Long
    'How many pairs of Open/Close brackets are there?
    'lBracketCount = Len(Text) - WorksheetFunction.Max(Len(Replace(Text, "(", "")), Len(Replace(Text, ")", "")))
    'This does not distinguish between correct &  misordered pairs

    'New code works in VB environments other than Excel VBA
    lBracketCount = Len(Replace(Text, "(", ""))
    If lBracketCount < Len(Replace(Text, ")", "")) Then lBracketCount = Len(Replace(Text, ")", ""))
    lBracketCount = Len(Text) - lBracketCount

    '  e.g. ")()(" will return 2, even though only 1 will be trimmed
    ExciseBracketedText = Text
    sExcise = "" 'This is the text to cut out in each loop

    While lBracketCount > 0 'Once for each bracket pair
        For lCounter = 1 To Len(ExciseBracketedText)
            If Mid(ExciseBracketedText, lCounter, 1) = "(" Then
                sExcise = "(" 'Reset the text-to-excise every time we hit an open bracket
            ElseIf Mid(ExciseBracketedText, lCounter, 1) = ")" Then
                If Len(sExcise) > 0 Then
                    'Replace the text in brackets when we hit a close bracket
                    ExciseBracketedText = Replace(ExciseBracketedText, sExcise & ")", "")
                    Exit For
                End If
            ElseIf Len(sExcise) > 0 Then
                'If we already have an open bracket, at to the text we will remove
                sExcise = sExcise & Mid(ExciseBracketedText, lCounter, 1)
            End If
        Next lCounter
        lBracketCount = lBracketCount - 1 'Next pair
        sExcise = "" 'Reset the text to excise
        'If the first open bracket is AFTER the last close bracket, then we can exit early
        If InStr(ExciseBracketedText, "(") > InStrRev(ExciseBracketedText, ")") Then lBracketCount = 0
    Wend
    If TrimSpaces Then ExciseBracketedText=Application.Trim(ExciseBracketedText)
End Function
```

Comment: Not really critique, more of a suggestion: If you replace the `WorksheetFunction.Max()` by a small custom `Max()` function, you've got a host-agnostic solution that should work in any VBA environment. ;) +1

Comment: @Inarion Updated, and added an early exit of the only bracket pairs remaining are reversed.

Comment: Nice one!, but maybe you should consider triming the result, to avoid double blank spaces. This UDF will return `508  609 ` (9 chars long) because there are double spaces, and also 1 extra space at end of string.

Comment: I'd usually leave the `TRIM` outside (`=TRIM(ExciseBracketedText(value))` so that the user has an option to choose if they want to, or at least control it from an optional variable.  For example `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(ExciseBracketedText(SUBSTITUTE("This is the (test) entry.  Do you think it is a (good) idea?", ".  ", ".__"), "  ", " [REDACTED] "), ".__", ".  ")`.  *Especially* since you should have a double-space after a full-stop before a new sentence... :P

Answer (score 0):

This UDF will look for **each pair of brackets** and will delete the content between them.

```
Public Function DELETE_BETWEEN_BRACKETS(ByRef ThisCell As Range) As String
If ThisCell.Count <> 1 Then
    DELETE_BETWEEN_BRACKETS = "ERROR: Only 1 cell allowed"
    Exit Function
End If

Dim ThisValue As String
Dim MyStart As Integer
Dim MyEnd As Integer

ThisValue = ThisCell.Value

MyStart = InStr(1, ThisValue, "(")
MyEnd = InStr(1, ThisValue, ")")

Do While MyStart > 0 And MyEnd > 0 And MyEnd > MyStart
    ThisValue = Left(ThisValue, MyStart - 1) & Right(ThisValue, Len(ThisValue) - MyEnd)
    MyStart = InStr(1, ThisValue, "(")
    MyEnd = InStr(1, ThisValue, ")")
Loop


DELETE_BETWEEN_BRACKETS = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(ThisValue) 'we delete double spaces

End Function
```

Note I added a [Trim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-trim-method-excel) at end **to clean those double blank spaces** after deleting each pair of brackets, and also **get rid of blanks at end of string.**

After testing it with value `508 (7S9 5DU) 609 (609)` (23 chars long) I get `508 609` (7 chars long).

Adapt it to your needs.